# Getting 'NLTK was unable to find stanford-postagger.jar!' error when using Stanford tagger

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp

I'm using NLTK 3.2.1, java 1.8 and stanford-postagger-3.6.0.

I downloaded the Stanford tagger with:

```
cd
wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-postagger-2015-12-09.zip
unzip stanford-postagger-2015-12-09.zip
```

And set `CLASSPATH`: `export CLASSPATH=/home/ubuntu/stanford-postagger-2015-12-09`

But I still get the error message: `NLTK was unable to find stanford-postagger.jar! Set the CLASSPATH environment variable.`

I checked old posts but none of them worked.

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize import StanfordTokenizer
>>> s = "Good muffins cost $3.88\nin New York.  Please buy me\ntwo of them.\nThanks."
>>> StanfordTokenizer().tokenize(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/stanford.py", line 44, in __init__
    verbose=verbose
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 719, in find_jar
    searchpath, url, verbose, is_regex))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 714, in find_jar_iter
    raise LookupError('\n\n%s\n%s\n%s' % (div, msg, div))
LookupError: 

===========================================================================
  NLTK was unable to find stanford-postagger.jar! Set the CLASSPATH
  environment variable.

  For more information, on stanford-postagger.jar, see:
    <http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokenizer.shtml>
===========================================================================
```

I got a workaround:

```
import os
os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = "/home/ubuntu/stanford-postagger-2015-12-09"
```

but why `export CLASSPATH` didn't work?

Comment: can you please share your python code which creates this error message?

Comment: @grubjesic Hi, I added my code which is the example from `nltk`.

Comment: It's `export CLASSPATH=$STANFORDTOOLSDIR/stanford-postagger-full-2015-12-09/stanford-postagger.jar`, you're missing the last part in your path export, see https://gist.github.com/alvations/e1df0ba227e542955a8a#stanford-pos-

Comment: @alvas I tried both, none of them worked. And [NTLK wiki](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/wiki/Installing-Third-Party-Software#stanford-tagger-ner-tokenizer-and-parser) says only directory is needed. BTW I already tried everything in the 'duplicate' post and stated it in my post, please stop marking post duplicate which is actually  not.

Comment: Did you try the solution on the gist? Also what is your output on your terminal when you do `echo ${CLASSPATH}`? I'm trying out the solutions from the gist and the answers in the previous SO post and it seems to work on a fresh Ubuntu installation

Comment: Which OS and version are you using? Are you using through the machine remotely or locally?

Comment: I suspect that at some point, your environmental variable was messed up, esp. when you use dynamic path instead of full paths, try the instructions here, they work fine on a fresh installation of Ubuntu (just verified that like 1 min ago): https://gist.github.com/alvations/dea35a07f1c520c1b0bff9db60adf85e

Comment: @alvas I found the reason now. `$CLASSPATH` only exists in current terminal. Before I set `$CLASSPATH` in one terminal and ran the code in another one.

Comment: `export ...` is only for the current session. To have persistent environment variables add the `export ...` line to your `.bashrc` file =)